# Explanation for maldetect advice

Tags: malware, session-management, apache

I received a notice from maldetect on an Apache machine I'm running, and I've not seen an advice like this before.  I'd like to get a better understanding of exactly what I am looking at.   I received the following email from the system:

```
HOST:      TheMachinesName
SCAN ID:   200811-0626.24321
STARTED:   Aug 11 2020 06:26:58 +1200
COMPLETED: Aug 11 2020 06:27:26 +1200
ELAPSED:   28s [find: 0s]

PATH:          
RANGE:         1 days
TOTAL FILES:   3
TOTAL HITS:    1
TOTAL CLEANED: 0

FILE HIT LIST:
{HEX}php.cmdshell.egyspider.240 : /tmp/systemd-private-6d8d11df4ce54accbfbfcec335e7cef7-apache2.service-K8b3wh/tmp/mbdvb0/sess_0a0651adaaf1f8f0cfc15ba2bd8069c3shells_wso => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/sess_0a0651adaaf1f8f0cfc15ba2bd8069c3shells_wso.11052140
===============================================
Linux Malware Detect v1.6.4 < proj@rfxn.com >
```

I see that Maldetect is kicked off every 5 minutes from a cron job, so it would seem that this is not a full system scan.   The malware itself is a piece of nasty looking PHP code.

Certainly nothing close to a full log (which would be inappropriate to publish, but I saw the below entries in my log file jumped out because (a) they are HEAD requests, (b) they have "interesting" browser identifiers which are different although coming from the same IP and (c) the referrer URLs seem odd, particularly as the sites in question are both focussed on English speakers in New Zealand.

Looking through the log files at the time in question (ie the timestamp to within 10 minutes of the affected file timestamp -

```
www.site1.co.nz:80 193.124.188.83 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:25:27 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 408 "https://nsk.dienai.ru" "Mozilla/7.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2006)"
www.site2.co.nz:80 193.124.188.83 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:27:08 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 336 "https://nsk.dienai.ru" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE4.00; Windows 2009)"
www.site1.co.nz:80 185.5.249.185 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:27:22 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 408 "https://zaym24-online.ru" "Mozilla/8.0 (compatible; MSIE5.00; Windows 2008)"
www.site2.co.nz:80 194.67.207.94 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:27:42 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 408 "https://otkormim.ru" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2004)"
www.site2.co.nz:80 185.5.249.185 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:29:06 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 336 "https://zaym24-online.ru" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.00; Windows 2003)"
www.site2.co.nz:80 194.67.207.94 - - [11/Aug/2020:06:29:22 +1200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 299 "https://otkormim.ru" "Mozilla/2.0 (compatible; MSIE7.00; Windows 2008)"
```

**Am I correct in believing that this malware exists in a session cookie, and the likely cause is that someone/something was infected with it or deliberately trying to attack my system - but that the result above does not in and of itself indicate any kind of successful system compromise?**

I did find [this advice on php.cmdshell.egypider](https://www.getastra.com/e/malware/signatures/php.cmdshell.egyspider).As it happens the server in question hosts almost exclusively Wordpress sites (unfortunately not all running the latest version/plugins- although none are more then 6 months out of date), and the server already has mitigations like disabling potentially dangerous PHP functions and PHP execution in sensitive directories disabled.

Comment: Still don't know all the details, but a system scan showed files affected for one of the websites on that server. (With same malware) Whatever it is, it has been dormant for a while (definately days, possibly months). The actual affected site was not one of the ones from the Apache log bit above.